# FTP: Downloaded a file to Mac OS and transferred to a Windows Server VM - but wouldn't work

Tags: windows, macos, ftp, endianness

I took an MS SQL database file from an FTP location to a Mac OS, then copied from MAC OS to my Windows Server VM.  However, the restore process for the database failed to work.  When I FTP from the Windows Server VM directly, the restore process did work.  What is going on here?  Could this be big endian little endian related??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End-of-line problem: an ancient plague on file transfers between operating systems, especially between OSX and Windows.

File systems use an "end-of-line" character to designate a new line, and different operating systems implement this character differently.  The Mac OSX uses LF ("line feed" in the old tongue) and Windows uses CRLF ("Carriage-Return-Line-Feed", as in a typewriter's cylindrical carriage returning from one side of the typewriter to the other.  Typewriters were physical devices employed to imprint individuals ink glyphs onto a piece of paper - [more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter)).

Hence, when you FTP the file to the OSX machine using ASCII mode, the FTP server changes line endings to a common format defined by FTP during transmission, and then OSX changes them to "LF" when saving the file, and your Windows machine ends up flummoxed.

Try FTP's Image (aka binary) mode instead, available using OSX's "ftp" command in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/  [More on using OSX's built-in "ftp" here](http://mmughrabi.blogspot.com/2007/10/using-mac-os-x-terminal-as-ftp-client.html).